# Async/await not working on Heroku but works locally

Tags: node.js, heroku, async-await

I have an issue with a post request which works fine when I run my server locally but doesn't work when I deploy to Heroku. The issue is with async/await and promises. Locally, when I use async/await I get an actual value and when I remove async/await I get a promise. This is what I'm expecting. However in my Heroku app I'm getting a promise no matter what I do. I've refactored many times with no luck. Here is a basic version of my code:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const user = "user"
  const org = "org"
  try {
    const newUser = await addUser(user)
    const newOrg = await addOrg(org)
    const newOrgUser = await addOrgUser(newUser, newOrg)
    res.status(201).json({message: "Success"})
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json({message: "Fail"})
  }
});

const addUser = async user => {
  return await db("users").insert(user);
};

const addOrg = async org => {
  return await db("orgs").insert(org);
};

const addOrgUser = async (userId, orgId) => {
  const orgUser = {
    user_id: userId[0],
    org_id: orgId[0]
  }
  return await db("org_users").insert(orgUser)
}
```

My problem is that newUser and newOrg are still promises when trying to addOrgUser so userId[0] and orgId[0] are undefined. This only happens on my Heroku app. Locally I'm getting the actual Id's. It very much feels like await is working locally but not on Heroku. What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Edit: package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.1.1",
    "heroku": "^7.47.11",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^0.21.6",
    "knex-cleaner": "^1.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Heroku build.log:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       USE_YARN_CACHE=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.20.1...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.10
       Resolving yarn version 1.22.x...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.10)
       Installed yarn 1.22.10
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - yarn cache
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.22.10
       warning package.json: No license field
       warning No license field
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 13.24s.
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       yarn install v1.22.10
       warning package.json: No license field
       warning No license field
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
       Done in 5.73s.
       
-----> Caching build
       - yarn cache
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 43.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v44
       deployed to Heroku
```

Edit 2:

response from addUser and addOrg is identical:

```
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624177+00:00 app[web.1]: Result {
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624192+00:00 app[web.1]:   command: 'INSERT',
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624193+00:00 app[web.1]:   rowCount: 1,
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624194+00:00 app[web.1]:   oid: 0,
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624194+00:00 app[web.1]:   rows: [],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624195+00:00 app[web.1]:   fields: [],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624196+00:00 app[web.1]:   _parsers: undefined,
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624224+00:00 app[web.1]:   _types: TypeOverrides {
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624225+00:00 app[web.1]:     _types: {
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624226+00:00 app[web.1]:       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624226+00:00 app[web.1]:       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624227+00:00 app[web.1]:       arrayParser: [Object],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624227+00:00 app[web.1]:       builtins: [Object]
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624227+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624227+00:00 app[web.1]:     text: {},
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624227+00:00 app[web.1]:     binary: {}
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624228+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624228+00:00 app[web.1]:   RowCtor: null,
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624229+00:00 app[web.1]:   rowAsArray: false
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624229+00:00 app[web.1]: } Result {
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624229+00:00 app[web.1]:   command: 'INSERT',
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624229+00:00 app[web.1]:   rowCount: 1,
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624230+00:00 app[web.1]:   oid: 0,
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624230+00:00 app[web.1]:   rows: [],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624230+00:00 app[web.1]:   fields: [],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624230+00:00 app[web.1]:   _parsers: undefined,
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624231+00:00 app[web.1]:   _types: TypeOverrides {
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624231+00:00 app[web.1]:     _types: {
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624231+00:00 app[web.1]:       getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624231+00:00 app[web.1]:       setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624231+00:00 app[web.1]:       arrayParser: [Object],
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624232+00:00 app[web.1]:       builtins: [Object]
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624232+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624232+00:00 app[web.1]:     text: {},
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624232+00:00 app[web.1]:     binary: {}
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624232+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624233+00:00 app[web.1]:   RowCtor: null,
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624233+00:00 app[web.1]:   rowAsArray: false
2021-02-03T02:47:37.624233+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

When I check the DB, the user and org records are inserted correctly but the orgUser record has null values for user_id and org_id. Locally addUser and addOrg return something like [4] where 4 is the id of the inserted record.

Comment: Please provide heroku error logs. will be helpful for debug

Comment: Provide information about locally installed npm, node version. Provide `package.json`. Provide `build.log` from Heroku. Provide normal (error) log from Heroku.

Comment: I'm not actually getting an error from Heroku. The orgUser just gets inserted into my database with null values for the user_id and org_id.

Comment: it would be very useful to see what is returning the heroku DB after inserting those entries. could you log its content? (what is inserted and what is the response)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I believe the problem is the version of discord.py. When you use `pip install discord.py` it only installs up to version `1.7.3`, yet for some reason for Heroku it installs the latest `2.0.0` version, which changes how the bot runs on startup. You can either specify in the `requirements.txt` the version you want Heroku to run `discord.py==1.7.3`, or upgrade the version you are running locally. If you choose the latter, you would have to change your code from something like:

```py
client.run(token)
```

To something like:

```py
async def main():
    async with client(): #or bot depending how you specified it
        await client.start(TOKEN)
```